# Current Location Not Display

Tags: android, google-maps

I've used below code for display current location.

But its not showing my current location.

I've enable setting-> location and setting -> use network provider and use gps satellite.

But not display the current location.

code is:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class ShowLocation extends MapActivity {

    private MapController mapController;
    private MapView mapView;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // create a map view
        RelativeLayout linearLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setStreetView(true);
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(14); // Zoom 1 is world view

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
                0, new GeoUpdateHandler());
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }


    public class GeoUpdateHandler implements LocationListener {

        // Called when the location has changed
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
            int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
            mapController.animateTo(point); //  mapController.setCenter(point);
        }


        // Called when the provider is enabled by the user
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}


        // Called when the provider is disabled by the user
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}


        // This method is called when a provider is unable to fetch a location or if the provider 
        // has recently become available after a period of unavailability
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you given the application the necessary Permissions?
In this case it would be : ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Comment: @VishwaPatel s. i've given above permission.

Comment: Take a look at MyLocationOverlay (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay)